# How can we configure the server URLs in React application that is workable for both local and prod environment?

Tags: reactjs

I need to configure the server URLs in my application which is workable for both local and prod environment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
You can create .env.dev and .env.prod. And create a prebuild step which would copy either file to .env
So you can work with different env variables depending on NODE_ENV

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: If you find anything else please do let me know!